# toString() in Grails Java Domain Class Causes

Tags: grails

By default, grails seems to return `<class name>:<id>` for toString() of an Java domain object. That's not at all what I want of course, so I tried to @Override
the toString() to return what I want. When I tried grails generate-all Tagtype, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a differen
t type with name "org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap"
```

My code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tagtype", catalog = "tigger")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Tagtype implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Attribute id.
     */
    private Integer id;

    /**
     * Attribute tagtype.
     */
    private String tagtype;

    /**
     * Attribute regexpression
     */
     private Regexpression regexpression;   

 . . .  

  @Override public String toString() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    result.append(this.tagtype);

    return result.toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed as it appears, from the OP's comments on the answer, that it was due to other plugins and the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overriden `toString()` in Grails domain classes without any problems, so that can't be the reason. [This blog](http://little418.com/2009/05/grails-throws-javalanglinkageerror-on-startup.html) suggests it could be a result of name collisions, either temporary (have you tried running "grails clean"?) or perhaps your class name Tagtype collides with some grails internals.

Another thing you could try is using different versions of Grails, especially the latest 1.1.1 if you aren't already using that. [This ML post](http://www.nabble.com/Error-executing-script-ListPlugins:-loader-constraint-violation:-loader-(instance-of-%3Cbootloader%3E)-previously-initiated-loading-for-a-different-type-with-name-%22org-w3c-dom-NodeList%22-td21274605.html) describes an identical error message that was apparently version dependant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to make sure my question is clear, I'm trying to override toString in a JAVA class, NOT a Grails class.

I am using 1.1.1 and I did do grails clean.

Comment: Since there's less "magic" happening in Java classes, there should be even less potential for problems. According to the article I linked to, it could be a collision between JARs required by a grails plugin and your own project

Comment: It really didn't make sense that toString() should have caused a problem. Unfortunately, I made the mistake of changing more than 1 thing at a time.

I was also playing with a couple of plugins (laszlo & zk). I'm not sure which one was causing the problem, but it any case it was an environment issue. I created a new app, regened and everything was fine. And toString() works as expected.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.